# Xamarin Forms: How to switch ViewModels?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

Switched to Forms from MvvmCross (mvx). With Mvx, in the ViewModel code, I use `ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>()` to switch. How do I do that with Xamarin Forms?
*Note: I don't want to add any code in the code-behind file.*

Answer (score 2):

`Xamarin.Forms` is *not* an `Mvvm` library. It's a cross platform mobile development toolkit. If you choose to go `Mvvm`, it's totally supported (and encouraged) by `Xamarin.Forms`, and you're free to pick any `Mvvm` framework you want. Hopefully those framework will provide to navigate between ViewModels in one way or the other.